# Merge sorted sequences with split and concat

Tags: algorithm, sequences, proof, correctness

I am struggling with following assignment:

Given sorted sequences of numbers [image: C1, C2, ..., Cn] and operations [image: split(C, i)] and [image: concat(Ca, Cb)], find an optimal sequence of those operations (the shortest one), which creates one sorted sequence.

[image]
[image]

I've devised following algorithm:

```
1. Sort sequences C1, C2, ..., Cn with respect to they first elements.
2. When number of sequences is greater than one:
3.    Find in C1 the last position with the number that is less than the first number in C2.
4.    If found_position == |C1|
5.        C1 = concat(C1, C2)
6.    Else:   
7.        C1a, C1b = split(C1, found_position + 1).
8.        C1 = concat(C1a, C2).
9.        Insert C1b to the set of sequences maintaining the order (with respect to their first elements).
10.    Remove C2 from the set of sequences.
11.    Go to step 2., in step 3. start searching from found_position.

An example:
1 4 5 9
2 6 10 11
7 12 20

1 4 5 9   2 6 10 11   7 12 20
^
1   4 5 9   2 6 10 11   7 12 20 // split
^
1 2 6 10 11   4 5 9   7 12 20  // concat
  ^ 
1 2 6 10 11   4 5 9   7 12 20

1 2   6 10 11   4 5 9   7 12 20
  ^ 
1 2 4 5 9   6 10 11   7 12 20
    ^
1 2 4 5 9   6 10 11   7 12 20
      ^
1 2 4 5    9   6 10 11   7 12 20
      ^
1 2 4 5 6 10 11   7 12 20   9
        ^
    . . .
    . . .
1 2 4 5 6 7 9 10 11 12 20
```

To maintain ordered working set of sequences, I could use balanced binary tree (insert in step 8 is nlog n).
Is it correct? How to prove its correctness?

Comment: What happens in step 4 if all of the numbers in C1 are less than all of the numbers in C2? In step 7, where is C1b inserted?

Comment: As for the proof, the number of concatenations is a monotone linear function of the number of splits. If your algorithm is correct, then you should be able to show that all of its splits are performed by all valid operation sequences.

Comment: <s>Lets assume that split can produce empty sequence.</s> Wrong. It'll generate excessive splits. I think that number of concatenations is exactly number of splits + number of initial sequences - 1, because with every split we must make corresponding concat.